# Image erases while double clicking on a PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, picturebox, double-click

I have written this Winforms application. Here is the [VS2013 solution in a zipped file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxVqTx5Vp2gjVTc1OFBCVHlkSGM).

This application is intended to draw only one line in the picturebox with the following conditions,

- Only one straight line could be drawn with left mouse-button pressed.
- If a second line is drawn, the first line would be erased and only the second line would remain in the picturebox.
- A double-click on the picturebox would open up a `PictureBoxForm` to display the line drawn on the picturebox.
- A right-button click would cause a context menu to be popped up to save the drawn line.

This application has one problem, **If I double-click the picturebox, the drawn line disappears** before popping open the `PictureBoxForm`. Only a circle is left on the canvas.

**How can I solve this issue?**

[image]

.

.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    #region ctor
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        
    #endregion

    #region Mouse Up and Down
    Point _startPoint = Point.Empty;

    private void left_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            _startPoint = e.Location;

            Circle tempCircle = new Circle(_startPoint, 10);

            Bitmap tempImage = new Bitmap(inputImagePictureBox.Width, inputImagePictureBox.Height);

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempImage);
            tempCircle.Draw(g);

            inputImagePictureBox.Image = tempImage;
        }
    }

    private void pressed_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (_startPoint != e.Location)
            {
                Line tempLine = new Line(_startPoint, e.Location);

                Bitmap tempImage = new Bitmap(inputImagePictureBox.Width, inputImagePictureBox.Height);

                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempImage);
                tempLine.Draw(g);

                inputImagePictureBox.Image = tempImage;
            }
        }
    }

    Bitmap _savedImage;

    private void left__MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (_startPoint != e.Location)
            {
                Line tempLine = new Line(_startPoint, e.Location);

                Bitmap tempImage = new Bitmap(inputImagePictureBox.Width, inputImagePictureBox.Height);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempImage);

                tempLine.Draw(g);

                _savedImage = tempImage;

                inputImagePictureBox.Image = tempImage;
            }
            else
            {
                Bitmap tempImage = new Bitmap(inputImagePictureBox.Width, inputImagePictureBox.Height);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempImage);

                inputImagePictureBox.Image = tempImage;
            }
        }
    } 
    #endregion

    private void showPictureBoxForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBoxForm f = new PictureBoxForm(null, _savedImage);
        f.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inputImagePictureBox.Image != null)
        {
            inputImagePictureBox.Image.Save(@"E:\___MSc in Computer Systems & Network\EMSC1,2,3\drawn.png");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing Saved!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is because any double click raises _MouseUp_ and _MouseDown_ events. But according the code `inputImagePictureBox.Image` is erased when `_startPoint == e.Location`.

Comment: See [How to: Distinguish Between Clicks and Double-Clicks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171543(v=vs.110).aspx)